# display the value entered in table

Tags: angular5

creating table and displaying value on clicking submit button. The value to be displayed on submitting data

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app1';
    private fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
    private newAttribute: any = {};
    addFieldValue() {
        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
        this.newAttribute = {};
    }
    /* ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.fieldArray);
    } */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a `recentlyAddedProducts` list in the component class and push the newly added data in this list. Then render that list in the template like this:

Component class:

```
recenltyAddedProducts: Array<any> = [];
       private fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
       private newAttribute: any = {};
       addFieldValue() {
       this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)

       this.recenltyAddedProducts.push(this.newAttribute);
       this.newAttribute = {};
       }
```

Have your template setup like this:

```
<h3 style="color:darkmagenta" >Recently added products:</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let p of recenltyAddedProducts">
      <span>
        {{p.productName}}
      </span>
      <span>
        {{p.quantity}}
      </span>
```

See the stackblitz showing the demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvfmfe?file=app/button-overview-example.ts

You can update your code to show only last 3 recently added products.

**EDIT**

To show only one recent product do the following change:

Component class:

```
recenltyAddedProduct;
       private fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
       private newAttribute: any = {};
       addFieldValue() {
       this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)

       this.recenltyAddedProduct = this.newAttribute;
       this.newAttribute = {};
       }
```

Have a template like this:

```
<h3 style="color:darkmagenta" >Recently added products:</h3>

      <span>
        {{recenltyAddedProduct?.productName}}
      </span>
      <span>
        {{recenltyAddedProduct?.quantity}}
      </span>
```

To show in h3 tag have a template like this:

```
<h3 style="color:darkmagenta" >Recently added products: <span>
        {{recenltyAddedProduct?.productName}}
      </span>
      <span>
        {{recenltyAddedProduct?.quantity}}
      </span></h3>
```

Comment: thnanks for helping. the data should be updated in table. only most recent value should come in h3 tag

Comment: @SudeepRanjan See my Edit. Also updated the same stackblitz.

Comment: @SudeepRanjan If the solution solves your issue then I request to mark it as "Answered" so that other members could take advantage if they have a similar issue.

Comment: can we do something such that the text: "Recently added product" is also visible when product is added. Initially it should not be visible

Comment: @SudeepRanjan - If I understood you correctly then you want this - "Show "Recently Added Product" text only when a new product is added. If not product is added then it should not be visible." Can you please confirm this if this is what you want to do? If my understanding is correct then add following in your `h3` tag `*ngIf="recenltyAddedProduct"`. Visit the same stackblitz to see the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ngIf that tests for the existence of the a selected product and databind the product name to the heading.  Create a recentlySelected property on the component and onclick set the recentlySelected property to that value of the clicked product or product name.

```
<h3 style="color:darkmagenta"  *ngIf="recentlySelected" >Recently added products:{{recentlySelected}}</h3>
```

Here is an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-click-zdb9ng?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Can you see the stackblitz example link?

Comment: See line 10 of /app.component.ts in the stackblitz example Add a line right below your title in the component.tsexport class AppComponent  {
  title = 'app1';
  recentlySelected = null;